# Function with multiple options of returns

Tags: python, function, return

Sorry, if this question was already answered, I couldn't think of a better way to describe this problem :/

Let's say I have a function like this:

```
def func(arg):
    if arg something:
        return a, b, c, d
    else:
        return False
```

So, when i call this function like this:

```
a, b, c, d = func(arg)
```

and it happens, that the function only returns False -would this create a problem (since I'm assigning 4 variables but only getting 1 bool) ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes it will raise a `ValueError`. You can take care of that by wrapping the assignment with a `try-except` statement:

```
try:
    a, b, c, d = func(arg)
except ValueError:
    # pass or do something else
```

Note that you can also check the validation of your returned value but since it's [Easier to ask for forgiveness than permission](https://docs.python.org/3.5/glossary.html) as a coding style manner, it's better to use a `try-except` for handling this.

Answer (score 2):

You can just test the returned value first, then unpack:

```
value = func(arg)
if value:
    a, b, c, d = value
```

Of course, you'll have to deal with what happens in the calling function when `abcd` don't get assigned.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, this would cause a problem.  Generally you don't want to do something like this, it often leads to unexpected errors later on that are difficult to catch.  Python allows you to break the rules by returning whatever you want, but you should only do it if you have a good reason. As a general rule, your functions and methods should return the same type no matter what (with the possible exception of `None`).

Answer (score 1):

Functions with heterogeneous return types are awkward for the caller.

Can you refactor?  If the `else` case is a failure mode, consider using exceptions for this case - python is not golang.

Answer (score 1):

How about instead of having mixed return types, just refactor to require the function to have a truthy argument and raise an Error otherwise? This way the Error will be raised inside the function and not on assignment, which seems clearer to me.

```
def func(arg):
    if not arg:
        raise ValueError('func requires a truthy argument')
    return a, b, c, d
```